# Pointer events on overlaying SVG elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/3m3dmdtw

I would like to show the "cursor: pointer" over some elements in these SVG files, even add on click events. 
The SVGs are overlaying.

How can I add a mouse-over on the "underlying element" - the blue rectangle? Is it even possible?

```
  <path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M338,293L338,293L164,230L164,230M338,293L934,307L733,59L164,230" stroke-width="30" stroke-opacity="0" fill-opacity="0" class="el-seq-7591 el-model-7591-76627 el-model-76627" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-76,79)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 0; fill-opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></path>
```

[image]

Comment: set the upper element as pointer-events="none"

Comment: Yes, that is the solution and add "pointer-events: all" to the required children.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I have found the solution.

The answer lies in "**pointer-events: none;**" which you can put on the "parent" element; this means that all pointer events from the child elements with "**pointer-events: all**" will be forwarded.

Solution in:

http://jsfiddle.net/klodoma/ox6pwjt2/

```
.stage-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.el-seq-7591 {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```